# Load JSON file for Grunt from node command line

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs

I have a number of different JSON files which I use for variables for Grunt to load.

Eg.

- project1.json
- project2.json
- project3.json

Each JSON is for a specific project which I load within a gruntfile.js along with the package.json like so..

```
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
template: grunt.file.readJSON('project1.json'),
```

When changing project I open the gruntfile.js and edit the above code depending which on project I am working on.

My question is, is it possible to define what JSON to load from the Node command line?

Thank you in advance :)

Ciarán

Answer (score 0):

if you run something like 
node myServer.js project1.json

you can retrieve those arguments in process.argv array

take a look to http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Comment: Thank you. Admitedly I am a complete novice when it comes to node processes but maybe this is a good time to learn:)

Comment: I had hoped there might be a way of creating a grunt task that could do it simply because I am slowly getting a bit of a grasp with grunt. Anyways... thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out using grunt.option

```
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
project: grunt.option('project'),
template: grunt.file.readJSON(grunt.option('project') + '.json'),
```

I could then call the json file from the command line using the following..

```
grunt compress --project=project1
```

Where project1 is the name of the json file (project1.json) to be loaded.